# Winsock error 10055 keeps reoccurring

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, socket

We are having some problems with Winsock after releasing a new version of our software. We currently have 16 servers running Windows Server 2016 that all run an instance of this software. All these servers communicate to yet another server that acts as a gate way of sorts.

All servers experience the same problem, which occurs after a few hours:

- Communication with the gate way server is lost
- Communication with active directory is lost
- Only way of logging in to the maskin via Remote Desktop is using a special login that doesn't communicate with the Active Directory server
- Error is easily fixed by running something like `ipconfig /flushdns` and/or `ipconfig /release`
- Restarting our application software also fixes the problem
- Running netstat does not show an unusual number of open ports
- Servers with a lot of activity seems to be able to run longer than those that are idle

I ran the PortQuery tool from mirosoft and saw the following error on most ports:

> Starting portqry.exe -n 127.0.0.1 -e 135 -p TCP ...
>
> Querying target system called:
>
> 127.0.0.1
>
> Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...
>
> IP address resolved to testserver15.test.com
>
> querying...
>
> Cannot use specified source port Winsock error 10055
>
> portqry.exe -n 127.0.0.1 -e 135 -p TCP exits with return code
> 0x00000063.

If i keep querying the return code vil alternate between 0x00000063 and 0 every second.

I have no clue what is going on here. Googling suggest looking into the number of open ports, but I can't find any issues here. Any idea to help steer us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you notice [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/399311/what-causes-winsock-10055-errors-how-should-i-troubleshoot) *(unanswered)* question? Perhaps there are troubleshooting steps you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The suggestions in that question mostly relate to possible limitations of x86, but we are seeing this error on an x64 machine.

Comment: Is your program closing connections and freeing resources properly? Have a chat with the developers. This is most likely to be a bug in the code.